# Loop through table column until a change is detected using vba

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, recordset

I have a table with employee names, weekDates, and locations for the entire year. Similar to the layout below. I'm using it for a calendar. The table has no weekends in it

Emp1 01/02/2017 Business1
...
Emp1 10/02/2017 Business1
Emp1 10/03/2017 Business1
Emp1 10/04/2017 Business1
Emp1 10/05/2017 Business1
Emp1 10/06/2017 Business1
Emp1 10/09/2017 Business2
Emp1 10/10/2017 Business2
Emp1 10/11/2017 Business2
Emp1 10/12/2017 Business2
Emp1 10/13/2017 Business2
...
Emp999 12/31/2017 Vacation

I need to loop through the records and find the first date and the last date for a location. The range is not always 5 days.
I want to end up with something like these 3 fields:
Emp1 | 10/02/2017-10/06/2017 | Business1
Emp1 | 10/09/2017-10/13/2017 | Business2

I know I need 2 loops but I can't figure out how to hold the first row value while continuing to loop to compare to the next.

I tried Gibraltar's suggestion and it looked like it might work but it only outputs a 1 day range for each entry. This is what I wrote using your code

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim bolFirst As Boolean
Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim strInstructor As String
Dim strDay As String
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strInstructorHold As String
Dim strDayHold As String
Dim strLocationHold As String
Dim strSql As String
Set db = CurrentDb

strSql = "SELECT tblTestData.RowId, tblTestData.Employee, tblTestData.WeekDate, tblTestData.Location FROM tblTestData ORDER BY tblTestData.WeekDate;"
    Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)
    bolFirst = True
    Do While Not rst1.EOF
        strInstructor = rst1!Employee
        strDay = rst1!WeekDate
        strLocation = rst1!Location
        If Not strInstructor = strInstructorHold Or Not strLocation = strLocationHold Or Not CDate(strDay) - 1 = holdDate Then
            If Not first Then
            Debug.Print strInstructorHold & ":" & strDayHold & "-" & holdDate & "-" & strLocationHold
            End If
            'Initial values
            strInstructorHold = rst1!Employee
            strDayHold = rst1!WeekDate
            strLocationHold = rst1!Location
       End If
    rst1.MoveNext
        holdDate = rst1!WeekDate
        bolFirst = False
    Loop
```

I didn't see where you initialized the holdDate variable.

Comment: Can't you just make a query, with a `group by` Location, with Min(weekDate) and Max(weekDate) ?

Comment: It normally would but it doesn't take into consideration changes from day to day. In some cased the location is "Unassigned" Group by shows the first and the last date for the Unassigned, not where that may fall in between other locations

Comment: _In some cased the location is "Unassigned"_ ... may I suggest you edit and expand the sample data to be fully representative.

Comment: You have to order by Instructor and type as well for mine to work. If you order just by `Date`, then you will get mixed/incorrect results because you'll get a different instructor/location possibly on the next line with the same date. `ORDER BY tblTestData.Employee, tblTestData.Location, tblTestData.WeekDate` would be the correct `order`ing. `holdDate` is my third line in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you will need to create three variables to hold your date, Current, Previous, Initial. Then, you need two to hold Employee Current and Previous and then two for Type Current and Previous. You also don't necessarily need two loops as long as the data set you are pulling from is ordered correctly.

I made a mock-up in Excel and will try to make it generic enough for you to understand:

```
Dim valCollection As Collection
Dim first As Boolean
Dim holdDate As Date
Dim firstColVal As String
Dim secondColVal As Date
Dim thirdColVal As String
Dim holdFirstColVal As String
Dim holdSecondColVal As Date
Dim holdThirdColVal As String

first = True
While Not empRS.EOF

    'Current Values
    firstColVal = empRS!employee
    secondColVal = empRS!date
    thirdColVal = empRS!type

    'If we are not the same employee or record type
    'or the date isn't consecutive with the last date
    If Not firstColVal = holdFirstColVal Or Not thirdColVal = holdThirdColVal Or _
        Not CDate(secondColVal) - 1 = holdDate _
    Then

        'Stop the first row from adding since it is a population stage
        If Not first Then
            'adding as pipe delimited
            'you can change delimiter or do something else with the data here
            valCollection.Add holdFirstColVal + "|" + _
                Format(holdSecondColVal, "MM/dd/yyyy") + "-" + Format(holdDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") + _
                "|" + holdThirdColVal

        End If

        'Initial Values
        holdFirstColVal = empRS!employee
        holdSecondColVal = empRS!date
        holdThirdColVal = empRS!type

    End If

    'Previous date
    holdDate = empRS!date
    first = False

Loop

'Add last item since the very last row will not get added to the collection otherwise
'Probably depends on scenario so you may not need it
valCollection.Add holdFirstColVal + "|" + Format(holdSecondColVal, "MM/dd/yyyy") + "-" + Format(holdDate, "MM/dd/yyyy") + "|" + holdThirdColVal
```

Answer (score 0):

Patrick, I revisited your answer but I also had to add a function I had to the query.

```
Function WeekNumber(ByVal vDate As Date) As Integer  
    'ISO week number Ref http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_ISO_weeknumber_en.html  
    WeekNumber = DatePart("ww", vDate - Weekday(vDate, 2) + 4, 2, 2)  
End Function
```

This let me also include the week number in the group by and that gave me the results I was looking for.